# How to shift spatial lines by different X, Y values in R

Tags: r, list, geospatial

I have a spatial lines data frame made up of 57 lines. I would like to shift each line by a different x and y value. 
That is to say I would like all the points making up the first line to be shifted by, say 100, in the x and 50 in the y-direction. Then all the points of the second line to be shifted by 20 in the x-direction and 150 in the y-direction.

I have used the shift function in the package raster, but it shifts the co-ords making up each line by the different x and y values

Perhaps I need to extract each line and then shift it, but I am not sure how to do this.

The example below with a two line DF. I would like the first spatial line to be shifted by (100,50) and the next line to be shifted by (20,150)

```
    #Make example spatial line DF  
a = c(1,5,2,6,3,6,3,5,7)
b = c(5,3,5,7,2,6,9,3,6)

SL1 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(a),a)), "A")))
SL2 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(b),b)), "B")))

SL <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(a),a)), "A"),
                        Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(b),b)), "B")))

SL.df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SL, data=data.frame(OBJECTID=paste(1:2),
         NAME=c("st 1", "av B"), row.names=row.names(SL)))

#list of x, y co-ords to shift each line by  
x<-c(100,20)
y<-c(50,150)

#Shift lines
shifted_lines<-shift(SL.df,x,y)

SL.df@lines
shifted_lines@lines
```

First co-ord of the first line is shifted by (100,50). The second co-ord of the first line is shifted by (20,150). This also happens to the co-ords making up the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
library(raster)
a <- c(1,5,2,6,3,6,3,5,7)
b <- c(5,3,5,7,2,6,9,3,6)
SL.df <- spLines(cbind(1:9 ,a), cbind(1:9, b), attr=data.frame(OBJECTID=paste(1:2), NAME=c("st 1", "av B")))
x <- c(100,20)
y <- c(50,150)

s <- list()
for (i in 1:length(SL.df)) {
   s[i] <- shift(SL.df[i, ], x[i], y[i])
}
ss <- do.call(bind, s)
```